# How to loop through subfolders in bash?

Tags: bash, loops

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for each in /mnt/hgfs/L/tempL/*.jpg
do
    s=`du -k $each | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [ $s -gt 10 ]; then

        convert -resize 1766 -quality 75 $each $each
        convert /mnt/hgfs/L/tempL/rotate_330_614.png -fill grey50 -colorize 40 miff:- | composite -dissolve 8 -tile -  $each $each 2>/dev/null
        echo "$each: done!"
    fi
done
exit 0
```

I want to process all jpg pics in tempL, includes its subfolders a, b, c, but this script only process the root folder tempL. How to modify the script it can process files in subfolders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `for` command with:

```
for each in `find /mnt/hgfs/L/tempL -name '*.jpg'`
```

Comment: can not run, it show error"find: `/mnt/hgfs/L/tempL': No such file or directory"

Comment: @yayahoho it means your directory is not accessible.

Comment: i can run with this "for each in /mnt/hgfs/L/tempL/*.jpg"  but for each in `find /mnt/hgfs/L/tempL -name '*.jpg'`  you give to me, it was error

Comment: thanks for your help, it is the path i make wrong, now it work now, here are new problem, if the sub folder name contain Korean word, special characters, it was run wrong, how to process folder name that contain special  characters ?@Ken

Comment: @yayahoho I have no experience in handling file names in other language. Other Korean character related site may help.